# Is the set $[0,\infty]$ Lebesgue Measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm learning measure theory, and I don't quite get how to prove or disprove if a set which is closed at infinity is Lebesgue measurable or not. Is there a difference from open sets?
All the properties in the book I'm studying are stated on $\mathbb{R}$ and it throws me off.

Comment: It would help if you included the relevant definitions from your book in the question. This is the kind of thing on which different authors will take slightly different conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extended real numbers $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ are defined as the set $\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$, where the symbols $-\infty,\infty$ extend the order of $\mathbb{R}$ by setting $-\infty\le x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and similarly for $\infty$. In this way, the new order relation defines a topology on $\overline{R}$ by considering the subbase consisting of all rays $\{x : x\lt a \}$ and $\{ x : x \gt b \}$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. With this subbase, all open (in the sense of the order) intervals are open (in the sense of the topology). This topology generates a sigma-algebra, the Borel sigma-algebra of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. From here, you can try writing your interval $[0,\infty]$ as union/intersection/complement of elements in the set of generators of your sigma-algebra to see if it is measurable.